# Debian multi-line prompt in konsole

Tags: debian, zsh, konsole

Sorry if I am wrong here, but I have no idea where to search for my problem.
I accidentally upgraded my Debian system to `stretch (stable)`. Since I did so, the `konsole` isn't working properly anymore.

I am using `zsh` with [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto). The problem seems to be with multi-line prompts, e.g. `pure`. If I use the tab completion, the whole setup gets messed up:
[image]

[image]

As you can see the test and cursor moves up and the whole layout is messed up. I honestly have no idea how to find the problem and fix it.

I am using Debian with

```
❯ konsole --version
konsole 16.12.0
❯ zsh --version
zsh 5.3.1 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)
```

---

Additional information

```
~
❯ printf '%s\n' "$PS1"

%}%F{blue}%~%f
%}%(12V.%F{242}%12v%f .)%(?.%F{magenta}.%F{red})${PURE_PROMPT_SYMBOL:-❯}%f
```

[zstyle](https://ufile.io/0pvyd)
[infocmp](https://ufile.io/du2pi)
[typescript](https://ufile.io/o7blh)

Comment: Please include the output of `printf '%s\n' "$PS1"`, or show how you are setting the prompt in your shell startup files.

Comment: I am using `prezto` as I didn't want to dig in how to configure `zsh`. The prompt is set there via `style ':prezto:module:prompt' theme 'pure'` if you are familiar with it. Worked fine prior to update, and still is fine on other system using Debian Jessie as well as the Windows WSL.

Comment: Can you also post the output of `zstyle` and `infocmp -L`? Also reproducing the problem within `script` and then posting the output of `sed -n l < typescript` may give more information as to how the corruption occurs. Is there any `preexec`/`precmd` hook?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I added links to files with the output of `zstyle` `infocmp -L` and `sed -n l < typescript`. Don't really know if there is a better way to do this here. A quick grep for `preexec` and `precmd` revealed several hits in `prezto`. However, I don't really know what I am looking for. Sorry that I understand so little, please ask if you need any further information.